# Javascript - parse locale datetime to us datetime format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I would like to parse datetime from locale format to English format (for .NET REST API Server). I use jquery datetimepicker:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('cs');
    jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    });
});

<input ng-model="$ctrl.startDate" class="form-control" id="startDate" datetime-picker/>
```

In datetimepicker i have for example this date `10.01.2018 20:15` (10 January 2018) and I need to transform to `2018/01/10 20:15`. This format is send to .NET server correctly. How to transform?

I need help with back way. I get date from server in this format: `2018-01-10T20:15:00` and i would like to show in datetimepicker in this format: `10.01.2018 20:15` How to transform this?

Thank you

Comment: check out moment.js...it does stuff like this easily in one line of code

Comment: Thanks I ty momentjs, but this throw error Invalid date: `moment('10.01.2018 20:15', 'd.m.Y H:i').toDate()`

Comment: I think its 'd.M.Y H:m'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple parser to get the components of your date string, then create a `new Date` and return the desired format.

```js
const datestr = '10.01.2018 20:15'

// prepend zero if less than 10
const z = x => x > 9 ? x : '0' + x

// parse formatted date into server date
const parse = str => {
  const [day, month, year, hour, min] = str.split(/\.|\s|\:/)
  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, min)
  const y = z(date.getFullYear())
  const m = z(date.getMonth() + 1)
  const d = z(date.getDate())
  const h = z(hour)
  const mn = z(min)
  return `${y}-${m}-${d}T${h}:${mn}:00`
}

console.log(
  parse(datestr)
)
```

Comment: This looks good. But I have a problem. This `new Date(year, month, day, hour, min)` return bad date: `Sat Feb 10 2018 20:15:00 GMT+0100`

Comment: @bluray - the `month` parameter is [zero-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @bluray I have updated the answer to fix the issue with the month

Answer (score 1):

With your conversion, you are trying to convert from a format which does not work across all browsers.

To accomplish this, you can split by a regex, in this case `/\:|\s|\./g` which splits by any `.`, `:` or whitespace.  Then you can build your initial date again.  Note that you will lose seconds, as you do not include seconds in your initial conversion.

```js
var dateStr = '2018.01.10 08:15'
var arr = dateStr.split(/\:|\s|\./g)
var finalDate = arr[0] + '-' + arr[1] + '-' + arr[2] + 'T' + arr[3] + ':' + arr[4] + ':00'
console.log(finalDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its not my case. I have date in this format: 'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm' and I need this '2018-01-10T20:15:00'

Comment: That format will throw an error in moment.js, as it falls back to something that is not supported across all browsers. Also in your question you ask for both ways to be transformed, please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I'm sorry but my input is this `10.01.2018 20:15` dont this `2018-01-10T20:15:00`

Comment: @bluray I updated my answer to only show the conversion you want.